# Does "composition over inheritance" also imply "composition over interface"?

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic, composition

I know inheritance means "is a" relationship, and it can also have polymorphic behaviour. But for example, in Java, the difference between extending from a parent class and implementing an interface is that the interface has methods to be implemented only. They both need the child class to depend on the parent class and lead class to couple to each other.

So, besides extending from parent class, should implementing interfaces to a class also be avoided if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The "composition over inheritance" principle refers to the cases in which you are trying to reuse code.

The principle says that it's better to reuse code by composition than by inheritance.

It does not apply to interfaces, as interfaces do not implement code that will be reused (at least, not until Java 8 :).

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces is one of the primary mechanism that allows you to invert dependency so that implementations can depend on abstractions instead of the other way round. Therefore, if you follow the SOLID principles, interfaces should be preferred over direct instantiation.

Like any other language feature, it can be abused or over-used. But when used for dependency inversion it basically enhances your program's "composition" by making it easy to extend your program's behavior.

Of course, if you're creative enough you can probably figure out how to do dependency inversion without using interfaces. Languages without interfaces have been doing dependency inversion for a long time. The stdio/iostream API is one of the best example of this. It allows device drivers to be written for new character devices without needing programs that write to stdout to be recompiled. Otherwise every time someone comes up with a new line printer, terminal or serial modem you'd have to recompile almost every program on your OS.